# Scraping website, can't nest data with similar name

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement, web-scraping

I'm looping through some data, which I'm scraping from some websites.
Currently I'm scraping the head.

This is an example of the data structure

```
const head = {
    rel_data: [
      {
        rel: "rel",
        items: [
          {
            type: "type",
            sizes: "sizes",
            href: "href"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
```

Whenever the `rel` matches, I want to insert the data into `items`

```
$('head link').each(function(index) {
if(head?.rel_data[index]?.rel == rel) {
  head?.rel_data[index]?.items.push({
    type: (type !== undefined) ? type : null,
    sizes: (sizes !== undefined) ? sizes : null,
    href: (href !== undefined) ? href : null
  });
} else {
  head.rel_data.push({
    rel: (rel !== undefined) ? rel : null,
    items: [
      {
        type: (type !== undefined) ? type : null,
        sizes: (sizes !== undefined) ? sizes : null,
        href: (href !== undefined) ? href : null
      }
    ]
  });
}
})
```

Like this

```
rel_data: [
  {
    rel: "icon",
    items: [
      {
        type: "type",
        sizes: "sizes",
        href: "href"
      },
      {
        type: "type",
        sizes: "sizes",
        href: "href"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    rel: "other-rel-type",
    items: [...]
  }
]
```

But what I get is this.

```
rel_data: [
  {
    rel: "icon",
      items: [
        {
          type: "type",
          sizes: "sizes",
          href: "href"
              }
    ]
  },
  {
    rel: "icon",
      items: [
        {
          type: "type",
          sizes: "sizes",
          href: "href"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I write `0`, instead of `index`, it works with the first type of `rel` (icon for example) but not the rest?

Comment: You are querying the index of html element in  the rel_data array. So the second icon will query something like rel_data[1].rel, or maybe rel_data[999].rel. Instead what you want to do is have a second loop that loops through all items of rel_data, or prepare your data in a different structure and then transform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to store the data in a temporary object rather than an array and use the `rel` values as keys.

Then when you are done use `Object.values(tempObject)` to get the final array

This object would look something like:

```
const obj = {
  "icon": {
    rel: "icon",
    items: [{
        type: "type",
        sizes: "sizes",
        href: "href"
      }

    ]
  },

  "other-rel-type": {
    rel: "other-rel-type",
    items: []
  }
}
```

Then a simplified version of your loop would be something like:

```
$('head link').each(function(index) {
    const rel = this.rel
    obj[rel] = obj[rel] || { rel, items:[]}

    obj[rel].items.push({type:..., sizes:...})

});
```

Then finally :

```
head.rel_data = Object.values(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been bothering me for some time now